# Grunt takes all CPU resources from Vagrant VM and VM stops responding

Tags: macos, gruntjs, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I ran Vagrant/VirtualBox on my MacBook Pro

```
  OS: Yosemite 10.10.5
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i5
  Processor Speed:  2.4 GHz
  Memory:   8 GB
```

After few requests it stops responding and I can't even `halt` it or `ctrl + c` it via terminal. All I can do is go to VirtualBox and to shut down it.

Installed versions:

```
Vagrant 1.7.4
VirtualBox 5.0.4
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5
```

Vagrantfile:

```
$ProjectName = 'projectdev'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64"
  config.vm.hostname = "#{$ProjectName}"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8888
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 15432
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.0.10"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
  config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.cpus = 2
  end
  #config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    #v.gui = true
  #end


  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "infra/bootstrap.sh"

end

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|

  #config.vm.share_folder "bootstrap", "/mnt/bootstrap", ".", :create => true
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "infra/postgresql.sh"

  # PostgreSQL Server port forwarding
  #config.vm.forward_port 5432, 15432
end
```

Thats how `top` looked at the moments its stopped responding

```
top - 18:58:37 up 3 min,  2 users,  load average: 3.55, 1.31, 0.48
Tasks: 140 total,   2 running, 138 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.6 us, 74.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 22.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   2049900 total,   930712 used,  1119188 free,    19608 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   170280 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                           
 1784 vagrant   20   0  756756 104628   7476 R 150.7  5.1   2:09.88 grunt                                             
   32 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.14 kworker/0:1                                       
 1921 vagrant   20   0  107696   2184   1180 S   0.3  0.1   0:00.06 sshd                                              
 1936 vagrant   20   0   23692   1700   1168 R   0.3  0.1   0:00.11 top                                               
    1 root      20   0   33640   2996   1492 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.26 init
```

Is there anything to be done for Grunt to take less resources and not kill my VM ?

Comment: I would ssh and run `top`
 to see if something is eating the CPU/Ram of the server

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Frédéric Henri, I update a question with top data of the state it freezes. Looks like its a Grunt who hangs up everything. Any idea how to debug it?

Comment: looks like a different pbm, usually it eats CPU when there's larget set of files. you can also look [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/grunt-is-very-slow-on-a-homestead-virtualbox-vagrant?page=1) for suggestions

Comment: Frédéric, it looks like the same problem, but no decision for it there.

Answer (score 0):

So seems I found an answer to my problem!

1. On MACs you should turn [`NFS SYNCED FOLDERS`](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html) on
2. Use all CPU cores
3. Don't skimp on memmory for Virtual Machine ;)

Also, I haven't tried this yet, but may be also a good optimisation! 
[grunt-watch-slow](http://tech.nitoyon.com/en/blog/2013/10/10/grunt-watch-slow/)